# Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget-package

I'm trying to install SignalR on Visual Studio 2010

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.2.2
```

and

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
```

I have the following error

> Unable to find package 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR'

Comment: This could be because your Nuget is set to look at a package source that isn't the official Nuget one.  Check your nuget package sources.

Comment: This is my package source : https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ (official)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tryied to specify a package source with

```
-Source nuget.org
```

It works!

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Source nuget.org
```

Comment: See, I told ya so :)

Comment: Haha yes :) Thanks you!